# How do I remove the area underneath an embedded YouTube video?

Tags: html, css, embed, responsive

I am trying to make a website and in it, I want to have a responsive YouTube video.

I looked up a tutorial on how to make the YouTube video responsive but the problem is that, it has created a massive empty area underneath the YouTube video even when I set the padding and margin area to 0.

Note: in the example below, the youtube video looks like a black rectangle.

I would really grateful if anyone would be able to work out what is causing this empty space under the YouTube video.

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica;
  background-color: #99DCD7;
  margin: 0px;
}

h1 {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 1vw;
  max-width: 60vw;
  font-size: 6vw;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}
#about {
  font-size: 1.15vw;
  max-width: 40vw;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  color: black;
}
div.latestep {
  font-size: 2vw;
  margin-top: 5vw;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0px;
  color: black;
}
.video-responsive{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    position:relative;
    height:0;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.video-responsive iframe{
    left:35%;
    top:0;
    height:30%;
    width:30%;
    position:absolute;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#mlep {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 6vw;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 580px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
div.orlisten {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 7px;
  color: black;
}
a:link, a:visited {
  line-height: 30px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
a:hover, a:active {
  line-height: 30px;
  color: hotpink;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
div.contact {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: solid;
}
#eop {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
div.form{
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>The Slightly Scientific Podcast</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <script src="script.js"></script>


    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>

    <p id="about">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis. Dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem. Nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi. At varius vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat. Vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros. Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam. Est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt. Accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor.</p>

    <div class="latestep">
      <p style="text-align: center"><strong>Our Latest Episode</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="video-responsive">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qu4zyRqILYM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <p id="mlep">Listen to our latest episodes on:</p>
    <div class="orlisten">
      <a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-spotify"></i></a>
      <a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-podcast"></i></a>
      <a href ="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a>
    </div>



    <p id="eop">Footer</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `video-responsive` class has `padding-bottom:56.25%;`, have you tried setting it to 0?

Comment: @rohitt Thanks for the comment but I do believe that line of code is what makes the YouTube video responsive. When I tried setting it to 0, the whole video just disappeared from view.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code was you have used padding-bottom. I have made some changes to code and I believe it helped you. If not please don't hesitate to say.

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica;
  background-color: #99DCD7;
  margin: 0px;
}

h1 {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 1vw;
  max-width: 60vw;
  font-size: 6vw;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}
#about {
  font-size: 1.15vw;
  max-width: 40vw;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  color: black;
}
div.latestep {
  font-size: 2vw;
  margin-top: 5vw;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0px;
  color: black;
}

.video-responsive{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
 }
#mlep {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 6vw;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 580px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
div.orlisten {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 7px;
  color: black;
}
a:link, a:visited {
  line-height: 30px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
a:hover, a:active {
  line-height: 30px;
  color: hotpink;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
div.contact {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: solid;
}
#eop {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
div.form{
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>The Slightly Scientific Podcast</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <script src="script.js"></script>


    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>

    <p id="about">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis. Dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem. Nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi. At varius vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat. Vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros. Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam. Est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt. Accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor.</p>

    <div class="latestep">
      <p style="text-align: center"><strong>Our Latest Episode</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="video-responsive">
      <iframe width="300" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qu4zyRqILYM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <p id="mlep">Listen to our latest episodes on:</p>
    <div class="orlisten">
      <a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-spotify"></i></a>
      <a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-podcast"></i></a>
      <a href ="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a>
    </div>



    <p id="eop">Footer</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you couldnt find what all changes I did.please ask okay..

Comment: Thank you for adjusting my code, that was really helpful. The only problem is that the video is not responsive.

Comment: You can make it responsive by using media-query. its not a big-deal..Please upvote

Answer (score 0):

If you look on `.video-responsive` has `padding-bottom: 56.25%;` maybe try removing that.

Comment: Thank you, but I fairly certain that the line of code you're referring too is key to making the video responsive since when I take it out or change the value to 0, the video just disappears.

Comment: @iwantlotsofcookies don't take all the padding out

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

`video-responsive` element's width and padding are used to provide dynamic width and height to the video. Video under `video-responsive` element needs to be `100%` in height and width.

In your case, you've added `30%` width and height in the video element relative to the parent element `video-responsive`, that's why you are facing this issue.

### Solution

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>The Slightly Scientific Podcast</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<style>
body {
  font-family: helvetica;
  background-color: #99DCD7;
  margin: 0px;
}

h1 {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 1vw;
  max-width: 60vw;
  font-size: 6vw;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}
#about {
  font-size: 1.15vw;
  max-width: 40vw;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  color: black;
}
div.latestep {
  font-size: 2vw;
  margin-top: 5vw;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0px;
  color: black;
}
.video-responsive{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    position:relative;
    height:0;
    width: 40vw;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.video-responsive iframe{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#mlep {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 6vw;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 580px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
div.orlisten {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 7px;
  color: black;
}
a:link, a:visited {
  line-height: 30px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
a:hover, a:active {
  line-height: 30px;
  color: hotpink;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
div.contact {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: solid;
}
#eop {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
div.form{
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
</style>
    <script src="script.js"></script>


    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>

    <p id="about">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis. Dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem. Nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi. At varius vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat. Vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros. Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam. Est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt. Accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor.</p>

    <div class="latestep">
      <p style="text-align: center"><strong>Our Latest Episode</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="video-responsive">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qu4zyRqILYM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <p id="mlep">Listen to our latest episodes on:</p>
    <div class="orlisten">
      <a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-spotify"></i></a>
      <a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-podcast"></i></a>
      <a href ="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a>
    </div>



    <p id="eop">Footer</p>

  </body>
</html>
```